# Create table and insert data into it during EF code first migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework Code First with Code First migrations.

During a migration, I need to create a new table, and then insert some data into it.

So I create the table with :

```
CreateTable("MySchema.MyNewTable",
    c => new
    {
        MYCOLUMNID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        MYCOLUMNNAME = c.String(),
     })
   .PrimaryKey(t => t.MYCOLUMNID);
```

Then I try to insert data with :

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.MyNewTableDbSet.AddOrUpdate(new[]
    {
    new MyNewTable
    {
       MYCOLUMNNAME = "Test"
    }
    });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I get an error :

> Invalid object name 'mySchema.MyNewTable'.

Is it possible to do what I need ? Create a  table and inserto data into it in  the same migration ?

I already have other migrations where I create tables or insert data into a table, but never in the same migration...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My recommendation is move that insert code to the [Seed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829453(v=vs.103).aspx) method. Migrations introduced its own `Seed` method on the [DbMigrationsConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829093(v=vs.103).aspx) class. This `Seed` method is different from the database initializer `Seed` method in two important ways:

- It runs whenever the `Update-Database` PowerShell command is executed.
  Unless the Migrations initializer is being used the Migrations `Seed`
  method will not be executed when your application starts.
- It must handle cases where the database already contains data because
  Migrations is evolving the database rather than dropping and
  recreating it.

For that last reason it is useful to use the `AddOrUpdate` extension method in the `Seed` method. `AddOrUpdate` can check whether or not an entity already exists in the database and then either insert a new entity if it doesn’t already exist or update the existing entity if it does exist.

So, try to run the script that you want this way:

```
 Update-Database –TargetMigration: ScriptName
```

And the `Seed` method will do the job of inserting data.

As Julie Lerman said on her [blog](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/):

> The job of AddOrUpdate is to ensure that you don’t create duplicates
>   when you seed data during development.

Comment: Wrong. The question is about EF core. Seeding is different there.

Comment: ** `Add-Migration "..." ` and `Update-Database` if first migration; `Add-Migration "..." -Context MyOtherDbContext` and `Update-Database -Context MyOtherDbContext` for all other DbContexts

Answer (score 24):

You can try this approach:
after creating table,
create another empty migration in your Package Manager Console using:

```
Add-Migration "MigrationName"
```

Then open the `.cs` file of that migration and, in `Up()` method, insert this code:

```
Sql("INSERT INTO MyNewTable(NyColumnName) Values('Test')");
```

After that, save and go back to Package Manager Console and update the database using:

```
Update-Database
```

Comment: If I put this inside the Up method I get Sql does not exist in the current context. Cannot resolve symbol Sql. Can you provide a more complete example of how you'd use this?

Comment: @egmfrs Are you using EntityFrameworkCore? This question concerns EntityFramework6. In EntityFrameworkCore, you would use `migrationBuilder.Sql()` (where `migrationBuilder` is the name of the first argument to your `Up()` method) instead of `this.Sql()`.

Comment: @binki Thanks, you're right - that does work. I'm using EF core and have been using both the accepted answer and your suggestion with success in my project.

Answer (score 11):

For those who looking for `EF Core` solution, In the `Up` method, and after creating the table:

i.e:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(name: "MyTable", .....
```

add the following code:

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(table: "MyTable", column: "MyColumn", value: "MyValue");
```

or

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(table: "MyTable", columns: ..., values: ...);
```

For more information see the docs: [MigrationBuilder.InsertData Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.insertdata)

Answer (score 9):

A way to do "random" things in migrations is to use the [Sql method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and pass whatever SQL statement you need to perform, for example, inserting data.

This is the best approach if you want your migrations to be able to generate a complete migration SQL script, including your data operations (the Seed method can only be executed in code and won't generate any sql script).

Answer (score 3):

First I run the

**PM> Add-Migration MyTableInsertInto**

then I got following,

**The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration MyTableInsertInto' again.
**
I have used following code for c# data migrations

```
public partial class MyTableInsertInto : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql("INSERT INTO MyNewTable(MyColumnName) Values ('Test')");
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            Sql("DELETE MyNewTable WHERE MyColumnName= 'Test'");
        }
    }
```

Then I run following

**PM> update-database**

Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [202204120936266_MyNewTableInsertInto].
Applying explicit migration: 202204120936266_MyNewTableInsertInto.
Running Seed method.

After running the seed method data base is updated successfully and this works fine for me.