# Create a seed migration in Entity Framework 6 using existing database data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a database with about 35 records already in it so far. I would like to create a migration for these records so that if someone spins up my project locally, they will have this data automatically populated. Is it possible to automatically create this seed without hand typing it all in EF6?

Comment: hi pls refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480481/create-table-and-insert-data-into-it-during-ef-code-first-migration Or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228056/generating-seed-code-from-existing-database-in-asp-net-mvc